# How can I (re)build the priority of a scheduled CMS component

Tags: intershop

I am currently facing a weird bug.

I have an include with a slot, I am fetching it in my ISML and I loop manually in order to get the position of each item :

```
//ParentSlot.isml
<isslotiterator Slot="#Pagelet:SubSlot("rajasmart_app_sf_responsive:slot.rajasmart.menu.catalog.pagelet2-CatalogItems")#" AssignmentsAlias="SlotAssignmentItems">

<isloop iterator="SlotAssignmentItems" alias="SlotAssignmentItem">
    <li>
       <ispageletassignment PageletAssignment="#SlotAssignmentItem#">
    </li>
 </isloop>

//ChildItem.isml
<isGetSlotPosition Pagelet="#Pagelet#" SlotPosition="position">
```

As you can see in the back-office it is the first :

[image]

However in my store-front it start with the third :

[image]

Do you have some ideas please ?

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the value for "catalog-3" is being rendered? What dynamic value are you concatenating to catalog- ?

Comment: Sorry. The value X from "catalog-X" is being rendered by the return of custom tag <isGetSlotPosition> and inside it : `<isloop iterator="Pagelet:ParentSlotPageletAssignmentPOs" alias="slotItem">
 <isset name="SlotPosition" value="#slotItem:Position#" scope="request">
</isloop>`.
So 'X' is the counter of this loop

Comment: I doubt that `X` is indeed the counter of this loop. The way I read your custom ISML module code snippet is returning the position and not the priority of this slot-item. And the difference between these I explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your expectation is that the priority shown in the management application is semantically the same as the `position` characteristic of `PageletAssignment`, then the answer is: I'm afraid it is not.

> The priority value is defined by the index within a sorted set of position numbers.

Suppose you have position numbers like (38,54,11,77). The algorithm sorts these numbers to (11,38,54,77). And the priority value shown would be (1,2,3,4). Basically the position attribute is *just* the value that is stored in the database. The priority is just there to help you grasp what is shown in which order.

You could use a simple loop counter if the position attribute is not suitable for you.